# QT Creator: Volume Slider Still Plays Audio When Program Starts

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am creating a music player program in QT Creator and I have encountered an issue: I have the volume bar set to 0, so it *should* be muted at start, but when I start the program the music plays until I move the volume slider which it then works as it should.

This is the volume slider in question:

```
Slider {
        id: volumeBar
        maximumValue: 200.0
        stepSize: 1.0
        value: 0.0
        tickmarksEnabled: true
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onValueChanged: audio.on_sliderVolume_sliderMoved(volumeBar.value)
    }
```

This is the method being called:

```
void Audio::on_sliderVolume_sliderMoved(int position) {
player->setVolume(position);}
```

I believe that should be all the relevant code.  Note: I'm learning to code with QT Creator by doing this project, so any extra input or explanation into this solution or my code would be nice as well.

Comment: Uppon object creation, there won't be no change and therefore no signal, too. Use `Component.onCreated` to call the function when it is initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply initialize it when you create an instance of audio (in your constructor) by calling your function and setting the position to 0 (ie: `on_sliderVolume_sliderMoved(0);`)

Comment: Thanks, you really helped to steer me in the right direction. My Volume Bar now functions correctly!